# The MongoDB collection document is expiring before the mentioned time

Tags: mongoose-schema

I have created a model in Mongoose and Node js for email verification, and the document expiration time is mentioned as 1 hour, but the Mongoose document is expiring before 1 hour.

In "createdAt" field "expires" time is declared 3600 but collection document has been expired before 1 hour.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const tokenSchema = new Schema({
    userId: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'user',
        unique: true
    },
    token: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now(),
        expires: 3600
    }
});

exports.EmailVerifyToken = mongoose.model('EmailVerifyToken', tokenSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the issue may be related to the structure of the createdAt field. The problem lies in the way createdAt uses Date.now() as its default value. Using Date.now() as the default value is only evaluated once during schema compilation, and that value remains constant for all documents.

Try to use this as a function to return Date.Now().

```
createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: () => Date.now(), // Use a function to get the current time dynamically
    expires: 3600
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It's working after your suggestion.

Comment: You are welcome. You can accept answer if you want to :).